# Tabs VS Menu hierarchy . Material design VS informational architecture

Tags: design-patterns, menu, information-architecture, material-design, tabs

There are two levels of menu. Tabs and usual sub menu.

The problem is when tabs are under  `home/manage/analytics`  menu - it doesn't make sense because hierarchy is actually backwards.

Because Every tab (`All, game 1, game 2, game 3`)  has it own `home/manage/analytics` page, not otherwise.

But this way it looks nice, there are enough space, #materialdesign etc.

So, somehow I need to place Tabs menu higher then sub menu to make it obvious that it's actually submenu.

It seems I created a mess and need a hint how to get out of this mess and structure UX wise.

How to solve it?

[image][image]

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using material design and you're looking for forward navigation (accessing deeper content), why not try to implement the structure they describe? The [docs](https://material.io/design/navigation/understanding-navigation.html#forward-navigation) say the following:

> **Methods of forward navigation**
>
> Forward navigation refers to one of
> three types of movement between screens to complete a task:
>
> - Downward in an app’s hierarchy to access deeper content, from a parent
>   screen (higher level of hierarchy) to a child screen (lower level)
> - Sequentially through a flow, or an ordered sequence of screens, such
>   as a checkout process
> - Directly from one screen to any other in the
>   app, such as from a home screen to a screen deep in an app’s hierarchy
>
> **Implementing forward navigation**
>
> While lateral navigation uses
> dedicated navigation components, forward navigation is often embedded
> into a screen’s content through a variety of components.
>
> Forward navigation can be implemented using:
>
> - Content containers such as cards, lists, or image lists
> - Buttons that advance to another screen
> - In-app search on one or more screens
> - Links within content

With this in mind you could have your 'all games' tab be your game overview page and have the forward navigation from there. So you could split into two pages having a game overview page and a game detail page, something like this:

[image: Game overview page]
[image: Game detail page]

Google Tag Manager has a different approach to navigation (with a dropdown and tabs), which may also work for you:

[image: Google Tag Manager]

Comment: This approach clarifies the workflow nicely

Comment: Great response with examples, you should've gotten more upvotes for it.Unfortunately all i can offer is +1